# Input Widget input type Number but with decimal value it increase +1 not +.1

Tags: javascript, html, outsystems

I I Have a input widget with input type number but when i enter normal value like 1,2,3 etc. and increase its value with increase decrease icon in input widget it give +1 value but when i enter decimal value like 1.2 or 2.5 it also give +1 value

So, What should i do that when i enter normal number like123 it give  +1 value ,

and when i enter decimal value like 1.2 and 2.5 it give +.1 value
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fm6Rk.png)

Comment: You can add a [step](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/step) attribute to tell how much you want to increase/decrease.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you want to handle this but you can try this:

1. Add an input field and add an onkeyup event to it
   [image: onkeyup event on numerical input]
2. Associate a client action to the onkeyup event, with a Javascript node:
   [image: client action with javascript node]
3. Add this javascript to update step based on the numerical value of the input:
   [image: Javascript to update steps based on numerical value]